# Setting UDEV rule for scheduler setting on USB drives fails

Tags: usb, udev, scheduler

I am trying to set different rules in UDEV to change the scheduler based on the type of USB media that is inserted.
For regular flash drives the scheduler should be NOOP, but for my USB HDD with actual rotational harddisk inside it should be set to BFQ.

However this always fails, because every USB storage device gets the ROTATIONAL=1 attribute in UDEV so there is no selecting on that basis.

So, this does not work:

```
# set scheduler for USB flash disks
ACTION=="add|change", KERNEL=="sd[a-z]|mmcblk[0-9]*", ATTR{removable}=="1", ATTR{queue/rotational}=="0", ATTR{queue/scheduler}="none"
# set scheduler for rotating disks
ACTION=="add|change", KERNEL=="sd[a-z]", ATTR{queue/rotational}=="1", ATTR{queue/scheduler}="bfq"
```

Any suggestions?

I am using Ubuntu 19.10

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by making BFQ the default scheduler and defining rules for non default media, so only rotational media uses the default setting now.

```
# set scheduler for NVMe
ACTION=="add|change", KERNEL=="nvme[0-9]*", ATTR{queue/scheduler}="none"
# set scheduler for SSD and eMMC
ACTION=="add|change", KERNEL=="sd[a-z]|mmcblk[0-9]*", ATTR{removable}=="0", ATTR{queue/rotational}=="0", ATTR{queue/scheduler}="none"
# set scheduler for USB flash disks
ACTION=="add|change", KERNEL=="sd[a-z]|mmcblk[0-9]*", ATTR{removable}=="1", ATTR{queue/scheduler}="none"
```